# Check if feature class exists using FME

Tags: fme-form

After reviewing this article: https://knowledge.safe.com/answers/50003/view.html

It is still unclear how to check to see if a feature class exists using FME. I was able to successfully read in the schema of the GDB, but what transformer is best applied to check the schema for a specific feature class name? How would the logic go?

Comment: AttributeManager will do that https://docs.safe.com/fme/2017.0/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/attributemanager.htm in the Example with screenshots shows you the process if it is existing or missing/creation required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First add the Schema (Any Format) Reader.

[image: Add Reader]

Next add a Tester Transformer. Connect inspectors to the outputports of the tester, this way the result will popup in a dataviewer called the Inspector.

[image: Add Tester]

Configure the Tester Transformer by hitting the cogwheel. Using a GDB as dataformat, fme_feature_type_name represents the Feature Class Name. Enter the Feature Class Name you want to check in the field "Right Value"

[image: Configure Tester]

Now run the Workspace.

[image: Run Workspace]

You could also use the AttributeFilter / TestFilter or other Transformers to process the Schema Reader output.